# RSS parser using React fails on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, rss

**Summary**

I'm using **[rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser)** in React to parse my RSS Feed.

**Problem**

When I first start up my development server, the data from the feed loads fine and my JSX is rendered. The issue comes in when I refresh the page.

The error I receive is:

> "feed.items is undefined"

This **only** happens when I refresh the page, otherwise, it works on the initial render.

**Component**

Here's my RSS Feed component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import RSSParser from 'rss-parser'

const RssFeed = () => {
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
    let parser = new RSSParser();
    parser.parseURL(`${CORS_PROXY}https://papabearcodes.com/rss.xml`, function (err, feed) {
      if (err) throw err;
      setFeed(feed)
      console.log(feed)
    })
  }, [])

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>RSS Feed</h1>
        <p>{feed.title}</p>
        {feed.items.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                <p>{item.content}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    );
  }

export default RssFeed
```

If I don't loop over the items, I can access the `feed.title` and refresh with no issues. Like so:

```
 return (
    <div>
        <h1>RSS Feed</h1>
        <p>{feed.title}</p>
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: Your initial state seems incorrect. If it's something like `const [feed, setFeed] = useState({ title: "", items: [] })`, you probably won't hit this issue since `feed.items` will be an array during the first render (right now it's `undefined` during the first render)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial state seems incorrect. If it's something like `const [feed, setFeed] = useState({ title: "", items: [] })`, you probably won't hit this issue since `feed.items` will be an array during the first render (right now it's `undefined` during the first render)

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import RSSParser from 'rss-parser'

const RssFeed = () => {
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState({ title: "", items: [] })

  useEffect(() => {
    const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
    let parser = new RSSParser();
    parser.parseURL(`${CORS_PROXY}https://papabearcodes.com/rss.xml`, function (err, feed) {
      if (err) throw err;
      setFeed(feed)
      console.log(feed)
    })
  }, [])

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>RSS Feed</h1>
        <p>{feed.title}</p>
        {feed.items.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                <p>{item.content}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    );
  }

export default RssFeed
```